# UIScrollView view port coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

This is how I am adding `UIScrollView` in my `viewDidLoad`

```
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)]; 
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; 
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; 
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES; 
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES; 
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width , self.view.bounds.size.height * 2); 
[self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

When the scrollView is loaded for the first time it's coordinates are : `{(0,0), (widthOfiPhone, 0), (0, heightOfiPhone), (widthOfiPhone, heightOfiPhone)}`

Whenever the scroll finishes, I want to get the co-ordinates of viewport in scrollview. How to do this? Thanks

Edit: 
[image: From the image, As the view is scrolling, it's y co-ordinates are changing. How do I track that]

Image Credits: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/

Comment: what do you mean by `viewport` ?

Comment: The content of scrollview that is visible on screen at any given point of time. Say, if my contentsize is 320*1500, on an iphone 5s, when the scrollview loads for the first time , coordinates of viewport are {(0,0), (320, 0), (0, 568), (320, 568)}

Comment: @VamshiKrishna your question is unclear. Add more details so someone can provide you good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UIScrollView delegate` method to detect when scroll is end : `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and in this method you can get coordinates of your `scrollview` and it's `content`. Btw `content's` cooridinate will be same with respect scrollview!!!

You can get `visible rect` from scrollview like,

```
  CGRect visibleRect = [subViewOfScrollView convertRect:subViewOfScrollView.bounds toView:self.view];
```

Comment: What is 'yourSubview'  here?

Comment: This always gives me ' {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}' output. If you see the gif I attached, y-coordinates keep changing.

Comment: what you want exactly ? do you want coordinates with respect to main view (self.view) or with respect to scrollview or else ?

Comment: see! If my content size is 2000, initially y should be 568(on iphone 5c)! If i make a small upward scroll, content y should be somthing around 800 right?
then another scrol
and finally
2000

Answer (score 0):

First, observe scrollview agent, and then implement its proxy method

```
(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: (UIScrollView *) scrollView {
    NSLog (@ "% f,% f,% f,% f", scrollView.frame.origin.x,
    scrollView.frame.origin.y,
    scrollView.frame.size.width,
    scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

This should be possible